# input box design is required

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need a search box which will look like the following picture given in a likn

http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JXn_3cD5gYk/U6VX61x1QbI/AAAAAAAAF2M/VJUHEfCu0f4/s1600/needed.jpg

I have designed an input field, which is given in the following code. What I want is the about picture in the link. I want to have a field exactly look like above picture but the

```
HTML
<html>
    <head>
            <style>


/*...........Search Products Start.............*/

#searchbox
{
    background-color: #eaf8fc;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;    
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #EDF1F2;            
    width: 300px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 1px;

    overflow: hidden; /* Clear floats */
}
#search, 
#submit {
    float: left;
}

#search {

    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    font: normal 13px 'trebuchet MS', arial, helvetica;
    background: #fff;

}

/* ----------------------- */

#submit
{       
    background-color: #B6C2C9;    

    border-radius:2px;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 1px 0 0 8px;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    width: 90px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica;
    color: #23441e;


}
/*............Search Products End............*/




            </style>
        </head>

    <body>

    <form id="searchbox" action="">
    <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Products">
</form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Please let me know what exactly I am missing, my [**Fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/CyAu9/).
I will be thankful if you help in in this. I think I need some more CSS, but unfortunately I am not that good in css

Comment: Here's a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/XFy4L/

Comment: Thanks for you reply, Dear if you look to the picture again. The button is with down arrow, and look like drop down menu. Please help me in this case how can I add this to the work.

Comment: Check this http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: @user3750236 I'm not a free consultant, that's why I gave you a starting point in a comment, and not a full solution in an answer.

Comment: I can not apply CSS on Div tag because I will change my all them. can we specifically target class of the field.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CyAu9/1/ might help...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ziakhan/qw96x/ Please if I am asking a weak question.. can I add the arrow with Products with css and in white color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="search"type='search' placeholder="Type here"/>
<input type="submit" value="Products" />
<hr>
<input type='search'results id="none"/>
```

css

```
input[type=search]{
    -webkit-appearance: none!important;
    color: gray;
    cursor:text;
    display: block;
    outline: 0;
    border:1px solid #999da0;
    font: normal 13px 'trebuchet MS', arial, helvetica;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 4px #ced2d5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:300px;
    padding:6px 20px;
    background: #fff url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/share-sprite-new.png?v=204b1e0e421b') no-repeat -271px -89px !important;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #ccc;
}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
-webkit-appearance: none;
height: 16px;
width: 16px;
background: red;
cursor:pointer!important;
z-index:2;
margin:-2px -10px 0 0;
    content:'▼';
    color:gray;
}
input[type=submit]{
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:4px;
    margin: -30px 0 0 188px;
    padding: 4px 25px 2px 4px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica;
    color: white;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
#none{
    background: none!important;
    padding:none!important;
    box-shadow:none!important;
}
```